# Access to the service is denied - Bing Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, speech-recognition, bing-api

I was trying to implement [Bing Speech Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx) in my application and after doing lots of search, I couldn't get the solution for this exception.

**Access to the service is Denied. Unauthorized Exception.**

I have the following code right now and I get this exception while the speech is being processed.

```
var result = await SR.RecognizeSpeechToTextAsync();
```

Am currently following this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx) link completely and I have gone through below links for the solution for this exception.

Link 1: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=aef27927-9a47-4ec1-9b2e-bd0664d70f91

Link 2: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/datamarket/archive/2013/10/21/new-bing-speech-recognition-control-and-updated-bing-ocr-and-translator-controls-on-windows-azure-marketplace.aspx

Still I couldn't get proper solution for my problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How many transactions with you remaining according to your Azure DataMarket portal?

Comment: @RowlandShaw No, I cant get you. Transactions in the sense? Its paid service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [your MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx):

> Bing Speech Subscription Requirements
>
> You can install the Bing Speech Recognition control for Windows 8 or for Windows 8.1 directly from the Visual Studio Gallery, or from the Extension Manager in Visual Studio.
>
> To gain access to the Bing Speech Recognition Control and the web service that it depends on, you **must subscribe at the [The Windows Azure Data Marketplace](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/speechcontrol), and then register your application. The subscription is free for the first 500,000 service calls per month**.
>
> When you are ready to publish your application, you can do so on the Marketplace. You can strong-name your application.
>
> For more information, see How to: Register and install the Bing Speech Recognition Control.

The section I've **emboldened** is possibly key here - you need to subscribe to the service via the [Azure Data Marketplace](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/speechcontrol), even though there is no fee for the first 500,000 transactions per month.

Comment: actually there is no fee for the first 5,000 transactions, 500,000 transactions cost (gulp) 1.590,20 € a month

Comment: a better link for the service is https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/speechrecognition